# Как залить на сервер проект VUE?

Tags: vue.js, vite, deploy

Vue3
Vite

Написал приложение.

Выполняю npm run build.

Заливаю папку dist на хостинг.

Запускаю index.html - белый экран.

В консоли пишет что скрипты и стили по указанному пути не найдены, хотя они там есть.

Выполняю npm run preview - всё работает.

Что я делаю не так?
Спасибо!

Comment: Или не туда заливаете или что-то с настройками хостинга, пишите в поддержку

Comment: А у вас сайт по домену открывается или домен + путь? Nginx конфиг увидеть.. Запускаете в виртуалке или контейнере?